# Haproxy backend server down due to layer 6 invalid response failed ssl handashake?

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, load-balancing, haproxy

The scenario is we have two servers which are in different network . We want to have ssl communication from client to front-end and from front-end   to back-end !

the front-end able to get ssl traffic and  terminate the ssl, after  that in back-end  ssl communication is not happening the error follows as

"***Server nodes/web02 is DOWN, reason: Layer6 invalid response, info: "SSL handshake failure", check duration:546ms "***

This is my hapoxy config file

---

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1 local1 debug
  maxconn 4000
  daemon
  uid 99
  gid 99
  stats socket /tmp/haproxy.stats level admin

defaults
  mode http
  log     global
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close
  timeout server 5s
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client 5s




frontend www-https
   bind  <Ip-address>:443 ssl crt /home/user/SSL/domain-name.in.pem
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
   default_backend nodes


backend nodes

    balance roundrobin
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix indirect nocache
   server web01 <IP-address>:8443 ssl verify none check cookie web01
    server web02 <IP-address>:8443  ssl  crt /home/SSL/domain-name.in.pem ca-file /home/SSL/gdig2.crt  verify required   check cookie web02
```

any help in this greatly appreciated

Comment: @ThiefMaster 
Please  help in this configuration

Comment: @dtorgo  Please help in this configuration